# Getting factory null in spring SessionFactory property with Resource configurated

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

The error is because the `SessionFactory` private proverty is null:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
providers.DataProvider.getAll(DataProvider.java:31)
controllers.JSONService.listDepartments(JSONService.java:22)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:185)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1469)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:699)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

The class that uses `SessionFactory` has this body:

```
@Resource(name="sessionFactory")
protected SessionFactory factory;

protected Class<E> entity;
protected String tableName;

public DataProvider(Class e) {
    this.entity = e;
    this.tableName = entity.getAnnotation(Table.class).name();
}

@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public List<E> getAll() {
    Session s = factory.getCurrentSession(); // The exception rise here.
    return s.createQuery("FROM " + tableName ).list();
}
```

Th spring bean at `applicationContext.xml` is:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="models"/>
    <property name="configurationClass" value="org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I´m doing something wrong?

Comment: How are you registering that class in Spring? Is it using annotation based scanning?

Comment: I dont know exactly, I´m new in Spring, For annotation, I just put that one that are in configurationClass property, I have to do some another thing more?

Comment: The class name that has the SessionFactory is DataProvider, where I have to register it?

Answer (score 0):

The only way an injection target can be `null` is if you created the bean containing it yourself. In other words, you did

```
YourClass instance = new YourClass();
```

instead of getting a managed bean from Spring's `ApplicationContext`.

Otherwise, Spring will attempt to autowire the field and throw exceptions if it fails.

Review your code.

---

<sub>Actually there are other ways for the field to remain `null`, but you really have to try hard so I doubt that's what's happening.</sub>

Comment: @EmersonFarrugia No, `CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` uses a `ResourceElement` object to describe a `@Resource` dependency. This object uses the `BeanFactory#resolveDependency(..)` method to inject the target bean. This method, down the line, throws a `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException` if no candidate bean is found.

Comment: My bad. I got my wires crossed with @Resource and setter injection somehow.

Answer (score 0):

You're either not telling Spring to create a bean out of this class, or you're not parsing your `applicationContext.xml`.

For the first case, either mark this class as an `@Component` and make sure a [component scan](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.1.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-classpath-scanning) is finding it, or declaratively define the bean in XML.

For the second case, read up about how to initialise the Spring context.